# getJSON displays [object Object] rather than actual values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, object

I have a JSON and I need to get this JSON and put in the html as a ul li list. It gets the value as object and displays [object Object] in html. If I modify the json then it works. so there is probably something wrong in my script where I am not able to loop throught he json file properly. Can some one help please:

MY JSON IS:

```
[
    {
        "us":"USA"  
    },
    {
        "fr":"FRANCE"
    },
    {
        "es":"Spain"
    },
    {
        "sa":"South Africa"
    }
]
```

AND JS IS

```
<script>
  $.getJSON('jsonfile', function(data) {
    var items = [];
    $.each(data ,function(key,val) {
      items.push('<li id="'+ key +'">' + val +'</li>');
    });
    $('<ul />' , {
      'class':'new-div',
      html:items.join('')
    }).appendTo('body');
  });
</script>
```

UPDATED JSON:

```
[
{
    "items":
        {
            "item":
                [
                    {
                        "id": "0001",
                        "type": "donut",
                        "name": "Cake",
                        "ppu": 0.55,
                        "batters":
                            {
                                "batter":
                                    [
                                        { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                                        { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                                        { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                                        { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
                                    ]
                            },
                        "topping":
                            [
                                { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
                                { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                                { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
                                { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
                                { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
                                { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                                { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
                            ]
                    }


                ]
        }
}
]
```

Comment: Could you say what result you want? "Iterating" is a bit too vague - what elements should appear on the screen and what data from the JSON should they contain?

Comment: @pimvdb: I need this json to parse using my approach:  http://adobe.github.com/Spry/samples/data_region/JSONDataSetSample.html#Example10.   the output should be the table as shown below the example 10 of link

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-access-a-specific-value. If you know the structure of the JSON, it should not be difficult to access the right values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `data` you're looping over is the array, which has objects. So your `key` will be `0`, `1`, etc., and the `val` will be the *object* at that position in the array.

Your JSON structure actually makes it a bit of a pain to output, because each of your objects only has one property, but the property name varies from object to object. You *can* do it, by looping over the object properties even though there's only one of them:

```
var items = [];
$.each(data ,function(outerKey, outerVal) { // <== Loops through the array
  $.each(outerVal, function(key, val) {     // <== "Loops" through each object's properties
      items.push('<li id="'+ key +'">' + val +'</li>');
  });
});
```

...but I'd change the JSON structure instead. For instance, assuming the keys are unique, your original code would work with this structure:

```
{
    "us":"USA",
    "fr":"FRANCE",
    "es":"Spain",
    "sa":"South Africa"
}
```

Comment: how would one get a nested json like how I have, using the approach I have used. e-g In your opinion what is the ideal way to getjson for this example http://adobe.github.com/Spry/samples/data_region/JSONDataSetSample.html#Example10

Comment: @Mike: *"how would one get a nested json like how I have, using the approach I have used"* See the first part of the answer.

Comment: If you see my updated JSON, I again get the object displayed. so it definitely depends on the level of nesting. is there to way that works for all levels of json nesting. Sorry if I am asking dumb question but I am new to json

Comment: @Mike: Can you do anything about the structure of JSON from server side?

Comment: @nhahtdh: No i have only js as an option.

Comment: @Mike: It depends which data you exactly want to access. If you have an unknown number of levels, then using recursion is a possible solution.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for the answer, but did you happen to look at my updated JSON

Comment: @Mike: Fundamentally nothing changes. Anywhere there's an *array* (`[` ... `]`), you loop through it (with `$.each` or whatever). Everywhere there's an *object* (`{` ... `}`), you have access to that object's properties and/or can loop through it (also with `$.each`).